# Chinese estimate for $\pi$. Were they lucky?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, irrational-numbers, pi, continued-fractions

The famous Chinese estimate $\pi\approx\frac{355}{113}$ is good. I think that is *too* good. As a continued fraction,
$$\pi=[3; 7,15,1,292,\ldots].$$
That $292$ is a bit too big. Is there a reason for such a good approximation that Chinese mathematics found, or were they just lucky?

Comment: I don't think they came that up out of thin air.

Comment: Neither I do, but... who knows? Archimedes couldn't find this fraction, and he is just behind Gauss as a mathematician.

Comment: ...just ask Gauss.

Comment: @joeA Gauss is dead...

Comment: I doubt it. You can get pretty close by adjusting numbers such as the 22/7 fraction. Enough time and you can get as close as you want

Comment: But to get close you must know where are you want to get close

Comment: Archimedes lived in 200's BC. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil%C3%BC, 355/113 appeared about 650 years later!

Comment: According to wiki, [Zu Chongzhi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zu_Chongzhi) allegedly obtained this estimate using the [Archimedes algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesAlgorithm.html) with a $12,288=2^{12}\times 3$ sided regular polygon.

Comment: @David H Erm... I'm speechless :-)

Comment: "That 292 is a bit too big." Well the Chinese certainly aren't responsible for that! Are you asking how the Chinese found the approximation, or whether there is some mathematical reason the approximation exists at all?

Comment: They not just lucky, 400 years before this estimate, there's a device with pi=3.1547, the later estimate is to make sure that the one make the former estimate does not know math well.

Comment: @ajotatxe I was making a joke about Gauss being arrogant, a la "Gauss *invented* pi... just ask him". And no, I am not an historian and I do not know if that is an unfair characterization.

Comment: @fedja lol, why?

Comment: @David H Because I understand why Archimedes stopped at $k=4$, but not why Chongzhi stopped at $k=12$...

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that [a Chinese mathematician can get an accurate approximation to $\pi$ by calculating the perimeters of regular polygons inscribed in and circumscribed around a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Early_history).  Then by trial and error or some other method, he can find small-denominator rational approximations to $\pi$.  It is not likely nor necessary that Chinese mathematics had some now-unknown special theory for rational approximation.

Yes, there is a good reason for a near approximation:  As you know, a [convergent $h_n/k_n$ is the best approximation to a real number of all rational fractions with denominator $k_n$ or less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations).  In fact, if $|\pi b - a| < |\pi k_n - h_n|$ for some rational fraction $a/b$, then $b \ge k_{n+1}$ (see [Proposition 16](http://math.stanford.edu/~jbooher/expos/continued_fractions.pdf)).  Hence, it is no surprise that 355/113 is a convergent of $\pi$.  Furthermore, the inequality
$$\left|\pi - \frac{h_n}{k_n}\right| < \frac{1}{k_n k_{n+1}}$$
given by [Theorem 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems) shows that the approximation $h_n/k_n$ is especially good (*near*) relative to the size of the denominator $k_n$ if the denominator $k_{n+1}$ of the next convergent is large ([Corollary 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems) to Theorem 5), which is the case for 355/113 as we see in the first few convergents of $\pi$: 3/1, 22/7, 333/106, 355/113, 103993/33102.

Your observation that the partial quotient $a_4$ = 292 is large is on target because $k_{n+1}$ is related to $a_{n+1}$ by the recursive formula $k_{n+1} = a_{n+1}k_n + k_{n-1}$.

By the above proposition, to get a rational approximation with error less than $|$113$\pi \, -$ 355$|$, we need a five-digit denominator!

Someone who discovers that 355/133 $\approx \pi$ is not lucky; rather he has a good understanding of rational approximation or is facile with calculations.  On the other hand, it is probably lucky that 355/113 is a near approximation to $\pi$ because [the partial quotients in the simple continued fraction expansion for $\pi$ are apparently random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Motivation_and_notation).